# Gif viewer like Preview on Mac OS

Tags: gif

Is there any application like Preview on Ubuntu that can view gifs frame by frame? I currently use gimp, but going through the process of going to filter > animations > playback each time I open a gif is tiring. I tried gifview but I couldn't get it to work